# Is there a way in SQLAlchemy to proxy a JSON field of key/value pairs to act as individual columns?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, polymorphism, parametric-polymorphism

My situation is similar to that of the [Vertical Attribute Mapping](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/examples.html#module-examples.vertical) examples covered in the SQLAlchemy documentation. However, the column names and values are stored in a JSON field as a dictionary. The types of each column are stored in another table with another JSON field (key/value, key being the field name and value being the field type).

Is it possible to create an association proxy that would treat the `kwargs` field's dictionary as individual, query-able columns?

```
class MainClass(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "main_class"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    # {"field_name1": "str", "field_name2": "int", "field_name3": "bool", "field_name4": "list"}
    valid_kwargs = db.Column(db.JSON, nullable=False, default=dict())

class ChildClass(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "child_class"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    main_class_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("main_class.id"))
    ...
    # {"field_name1": "test", "field_name2": 1, "field_name3": False, "field_name4": ["a", "b", "c"]}
    kwargs = db.Column(db.JSON, nullable=False, default=dict())
```